# Enabling json calbacks in Alfresco 4.0

Tags: json, jsonp, alfresco

Hello I'm in a bit of a jam here.

I'm trying to activate json calbacks (jsonp) on Alfresco 4.0.b following these directives.
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts#JSON_Callbacks

If I understand correctly for me to activate this feature for webscripts I need to modify this file /Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/web-scripts-application-context.xml and add a property 
`<property name="allowCallbacks"><value>true</value></property>` 
to any bean definition I want json callbacks on.

Now from what I read everywhere you should never ever modify files inside alfresco.war or share.war. So here is my question:

How would I go about modifying this file outside of the alfresco war?

I tried copying the file to /Alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-scripts-application-context.xml and adding the propertie to the webscripts.container bean and the webscripts.authenticator.basic bean but both my script and the basic authentication script are not returning my results wrappped in my my_function when I use alf_callback=my_function

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: No clue to be honest. But, be sure to include the whole bean from the original xml file not only the "diff" because you are overriding the whole bean.

Answer (score 1):

Just placing a customized copy in `shared/classes/alfresco` does not work as beans still resolve from `alfresco/WEB-INFO/classes/alfresco`.

Try putting your customizations in `shared/classes/alfresco/extension/whatever-context.xml`.

The order of the imports is defined in `alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/application-context.xml` - the last definition overrides and "wins".

Comment: I tried moving the file to shared/classes/alfresco/extension/web-scripts-application-context.xml. I included the complete definition with the allowCallbacks propertie for the webscripts.container bean and the webscripts.authenticator.basic. I also had to add the also included the beans webscripts.index.prototype and webscripts.registry.prototype as there were dependencies to them in the WebScripts.container bean. So far nothing indicates that my property is taken into account. I still don't receive my Jason result wrapped in my callback function.

Comment: Try setting the loglevel of org.springframework to info. The output will tell which bean definition is used and from which file it was read.

Comment: I verified the logs and the bean definition is being replaced by the one I supplied in  shared/classes/alfresco/extension/mxa-web-scripts-application-context.xml. So its either that the property allowCallbacks is not taken into account by alfresco or I'm modifying the wrong bean. I already started exploring other solution for cross domain JavaScript requests in case this doesn't work out